# Disable Button If Checkbox Is Unchecked In Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm working on this web application. I have a list of categories, where if an item on the list is not checked, the "Save"and "Publish"buttons would be disabled. I understand `ng-disabled = !(ng-model name)`would do just that, but each time, I load the page, the buttons are disabled, but do not get enabled when I check an item on the list.

```
<a ng-if="status() < 2" href="#" data-ng-click="publish(true)" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-success" ng-disabled="!cat.IsSelected">{{lbl.publish}}</a>
<a ng-if="status() == 2" href="#" data-ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary" id="check_box" ng-disabled="!cat.IsSelected">
{{lbl.save}}
</a>                       
<span ng-if="status() < 2">
   <a href="#" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary"   id="check_box" ng-disabled="!cat.IsSelected">
    {{lbl.save}}
   </a>
</span>

<ul class="categories-list">
    <li ng-repeat="cat in lookups.CategoryList">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="cat-{{cat.OptionValue}}" data-ng-model="cat.IsSelected"/> {{cat.OptionName}}</label>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="lookups.CategoryList.length == 0" class="item-empty">{{lbl.empty}}</li>
</ul>
```

JS Code:

```
$scope.post.Categories = [];
if ($scope.lookups.CategoryList != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.lookups.CategoryList.length; i++) {
        var cat = $scope.lookups.CategoryList[i];
        if (cat.IsSelected) {
            var catAdd = { "IsChecked": false, "Id": cat.OptionValue, "Title": cat.OptionName };
            $scope.post.Categories.push(catAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ng-disabled`(`disable` attribute) doesn't work on anchor tag..

Comment: You don't really "disable" an `<a>` element.  Perhaps the logic in `save()` can check your condition and simply not perform its logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** made the fiddle more like the actual scenario.

Wrap your `<a>` tag in a button and put the `ng-dissabled` on that.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates how I would do this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wwxeerp/17/)

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="!hasSelectedAnItem" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary">
    Save
  </button>
  <ul class="categories-list">
      <li ng-repeat="cat in items">
          <label><input type="checkbox" id="cat-{{cat.OptionValue}}" ng-model="cat.IsSelected" ng-change="canBeSaved()"/> {{cat.OptionName}}</label>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.hasSelectedAnItem = false;

   $scope.items = [
        {OptionValue: 123, OptionName: "Adam", IsSelected: true},
      {OptionValue: 234, OptionName: "Paul", IsSelected: false},
            {OptionValue: 345, OptionName: "Jason", IsSelected: true},          
      {OptionValue: 464, OptionName: "Joe", IsSelected: false}
   ];

   $scope.canBeSaved = function() {

      var found = false;
        $scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.IsSelected) {
            alert("Here");
            found = true; 
        }
      });

      $scope.hasSelectedAnItem = found;
   }

   $scope.save = function() {
        alert($scope.cat.IsSelected);
   }

   $scope.canBeSaved();
}]);
```

Comment: @gbade_ I added a fiddle and the code. See if this will work for you.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I have even modified the code in jsfiddler to include a checkbox.  It works in jsFiddler. The challenge is using that code with a list of checkbox items. The button stays disabled, but nothing happens when checked or unchecked

Comment: What happens if you wrap it in a timeout? Also, do you have one save button for all of your categories, or does each category have its own save button?

Comment: Yes, one save button.The save button picks the selected items, and adds them to an array of objects. The list of checkboxes ought to ensure the user selects an item before saving.

Comment: Okay...I believe I have replicated your situation. Check out the fiddle for how I did it. Something like that will work for you.

Comment: Just did that. Once again. Thanks.