# Disable button when a checkbox in a ng-repeat list is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have a button that I need to disable if the there is no checked checkbox on my ng-repeat.

```
<button class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rejectModal" contenteditable="false" id="delbutton" ng-model="delbutton" ng-disabled="!item.checked">
```

and my checkbox is like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select" value="checked" ng-model="item.checked"/>
```

How can I possibly do this?

Comment: Is your button also on the repeater group along with a checkbox?

Comment: @Kalyan no its not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Button If Checkbox Is Unchecked In Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142514/disable-button-if-checkbox-is-unchecked-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the plunker for your problem. [https://plnkr.co/edit/AIrKVLedt6mcggvpmJE2?p=preview][1]

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.Items = [
    {checked:false},
  {checked:true},
  {checked:false},
  ];

  $scope.setButtonEnabled = function(itemchecked){
      var isButtonEnabled =false;
      angular.forEach( $scope.Items, function(item){
        if(item && item.checked)
           isButtonEnabled = true;
      });
      return  isButtonEnabled;
  };
});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Items">
      <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="checked" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="setButtonEnabled()" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <button  id="delbutton"  ng-disabled="setButtonEnabled()">Submit</button>
```